# Вопрос по циклу

Tags: android, циклы, if

Здравствуйте.
Есть один цикл.

```
   for (int i = 30; i <= msb.length - 1; i = i + 6) {
                if (i == msb.length - 6){

                Record record = new Record(msb[i], msb[i + 1], msb[i + 2],
                        msb[i + 3], msb[i + 4], msb[i + 5], msb[i + 6],
                        msb[i + 8]);

                record.Save();
                titleList.add(record.toString());
                break;
                }
            }
```

От него мне надо, чтобы он проходил по массиву, начиная с 30 элемента, и следующие элементы т е 31-36,38 запоминал в рекорд и отправлял.
Я вставил еще одно условие if внутри цикла, чтобы он останавливался после окончания элементов в массиве т к без if андроид крашится.
Но я никак не могу проверить его в дебаггере - где бы не поставил внутри цикла точку, программа на ней не останавливается.

Если меняю условие if на i<=msb.length - 1 и указываю вывод какого-то элемента массива, который должен выводиться, например, через каждые 8 элементов, то выводится только первый почему-то.
Подскажите, все ли делаю правильно?

Сменил условие на:

```
for (int i = 31; i < msb.length - 8; i = i + 14) {
```

и заработало, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Рекомендую писать: `for (int i = 31; i < (msb.length - 8); i+=14)` - так читается лучше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваше условие сработает только в том случае, если `msb.length` кратно 6. Внутри условия Вы пишете `msb[i + 8]` - то есть, i должно быть меньше `msb.length` хотя бы на 8. А оно у Вас гарантировано таким не будет. Вот это и есть основной причиной падения - выход за пределы массива.

Рекомендую просто на листике расчитать индексы и посмотреть.

Comment: Я рассчитал вывод - с 30 элемента выводить 31-36 и 38 элементы друг за другом и на следующих кругах к этим элементам прибавлять 6 и выводить соответственно далее 31+6, 32+6 и т д 38+6... пока не закончится массив.
Но как его остановить - не совсем понимаю.

Comment: я бы для начала заменил условие

    i <= msb.length - 1

на 

    i < msb.length - 8